# Задача Twosum с усложнением под range

Tags: python, алгоритм

Дан список целых чисел и число-цель. Нужно найти такой range, чтобы сумма его элементов давала число-цель.

> elements = [1, -3, 4, 5]
>
> target = 9
>
> result = range(2, 4) # because elements[2] + elements[3] == target

Хочется понять основную идею, чем тут можно дополнительно воспользоваться, чтобы решить за линейное время.

Самое очевидное решение, это - брать элемент и суммировать все последующие элементы до конца и проверять было ли в процессе значение равное `target`, но тогда это будет довольно долго, потому что N итераций с первого элемента, N - 1 итераций со второго элемента и т.д, получается примерно квадратичная. А как можно лучше?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Алгоритм простой как два рубля.

У вас есть массив. Вы можете посчитать сумму префиксов в массиве, например `SumX1` и `SumX2` - будут суммы от `0` до `X1` и от `0` до `X2` (где `X2 > X1`)

Тогда сумма итервала между `X1` и `X2` будет равна `SumX2-SumX1`.

[image]

Наша задача найти такие суммы интервалов `SumX2-SumX1 = target`.

Так как в каждый момент времени мы вычисляем SumX2 (все суммы до X2 уже вычислены), то немного переделав урвнение `SumX2-SumX1 = target` ==> `SumX2-target = SumX1` мы понимаем, какую уже вычисленную сумму искать в мапе - ту, которая равнв `SumX2-target`.

Код на C# будет выглядеть как то так

```
void printIntervals(int[] data, int target)
{
    var prefixSums = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += data[i];

        if (sum == target) Console.WriteLine($"0 - {i}");
        if (prefixSums.ContainsKey(sum - target))
        {
            var indices = prefixSums[sum - target];
            foreach (var ind in indices) Console.WriteLine($"{ind + 1} - {i}");
        }
        if (!prefixSums.ContainsKey(sum)) prefixSums[sum] = new List<int>() { i };
        else prefixSums[sum].Add(i);
    }
}
```

Проверка

```
printIntervals(new int[] {1, -3, 4, 5}, 9);
```

Вывод

```
2 - 3
```

Так и получается, сумма в интервале `[2,3]` (или интервале `[2,4)`) равна 9.

Поъожая [задача на литкоде](https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-sum-equals-k/editorial/), там в разборе даже гифка есть =)

Comment: Надо картинки нарисовать, так всё-равно никак не могу понять я лично ))

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил картинку ))

Comment: Спасибо, примерно понял)

Answer (score 2):

Реализация алгоритма от tym32167 на Python. Вдруг кому пригодится.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import accumulate


def printIntervals(elements: list[int], target: int) -> list[tuple]:
    sum_dict: defaultdict = defaultdict(list[int])
    result_list: list[tuple] = list()

    # Суммируем элементы списка по нарастающей и сохраняем в словаре
    # ключ: сумма, значение: список индексов для каждой суммы
    for id_to, sum_accum in enumerate(accumulate(elements)):
        
        if sum_accum == target:
            result_list.append((0, id_to))
    
        for id_from in sum_dict.get((sum_accum - target),[]):
            result_list.append((id_from + 1, id_to))
    
        sum_dict[sum_accum].append(id_to)

    return(result_list)


result = printIntervals([1, -3, 4, 5], 9)
print(result)  # [(2, 3)]

result = printIntervals([1, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, -3, 4, 5, -5, 5], 9)
print(result)  # [(0, 4), (2, 4), (1, 5), (4, 8), (4, 10), (7, 8), (7, 10)]
```

Comment: Важная часть алгоритма (что этого, что для 2Sum проблемы) в том, что мы для каждой суммы сначала ищем ей пару, а потом уже добавляем её в хешмапу, чтобы не париться, если наша же сумма сама себе будет парой. Такое может случиться, например, при target=0.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Код исправил. Теперь target=0 отрабатывает корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Считать кумулятивные суммы (от начала до текущего элемента), складывать их в мап (словарь), для каждой суммы `S` проверять, нет ли в мапе значения `S-target`

Comment: Ну и проверять, не равны ли S и target

Comment: @tym32167  Можно в словарь 0 занести, чтобы отдельно проверку не делать

Comment: Как вариант, согласен :)

Comment: Но ведь всё-равно придётся для каждого `N`-го элемента обновлять все текущие кумулятивные суммы, от всех элементов начиная от `1`-го до `N-1`-го, то есть всё-равно `O(n^2)` будет?

Comment: @CrazyElf зачем? Сумма от 0 до Nго элемента одна, значит, чтобы дургой префикс от 0 до X (X<N) подходил, у него должна быть конкртеня сумма. Значит, если мы соберем все префиксы с конкретной суммой, в мапе они будут в одном ключе. Зачем что то где то обновлять?

Comment: @tym32167 А, ну ок, ключей в мапе будет меньше, чем элементов последовательности (возможно), но как проверять, что мы нашли нужную сумму - нужно же будет с каждым новым элементом `N` обновлять ключи маппинга и сравнивать их с искомым значением?

Comment: @CrazyElf накатал код =)

Comment: @MBo сорян, что стырил ответ. Я просто видел вопрос еще до вашего ответа, но не успел вовремя добежать до копма код накидать. Сначала подумал, что вашего ответа достаточно, но потом увидел доп вопросы под ним и дальше всё как в тумане 

Comment: @tym32167   `и дальше всё как в тумане` классная отмазка ;-))